# How can I add dependancies to a Spring Tool Suite 4 project?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Using STS 3.7, I created a new "Spring Starter Project" by right clicking in the package explorer and selecting new -> Spring Starter Project and, of course, selecting what I needed.

Now, I would like to add JPA to it. I looked at some sample JPA projects and see there are many dependencies, and I'm thinking they vary based upon what persistence engine I'm going to use.

So, I'm wondering if there is an easy way to edit the project to add what the starter project creation feature would have if I had selected it in the first place.

Failing that, whats the best way to figure out what dependancies are needed for any particular thing and add them? I tried a few different things but the only result was a broken project.

Thanks very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click on the generated pom file, there is an option "Spring -> Edit Starters" where you can add more of the Spring Boot starters. This is what you are looking for, I guess. In addition to that I would like to recommend the guides at http://spring.io/guides, if you are looking for additional advice. There are a bunch of data related guides as well. Hope this helps!